# Tangent space of statistical manifold (information geometry)

Tags: probability-theory, smooth-manifolds, geometric-probability

I am currently reading http://www.danielwagenaar.net/papers/98-Wage2.pdf, where at page 8 it creates a bijection between $T_pM$ and a vector space which basis is $ \partial_\theta l(\theta)$, where $l(\theta)=\ln (p_\theta (x))$ and $p_{\theta}$ is a probability distribution.

My only problem with this is: Why are the derivatives of $l(\theta)$ linearly independent and thus form a vector space? I have been trying to show it using the usual definition of linearly independency but I can not come up with a contradiction.

What is the intuition behind this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\partial_\theta\ell(\theta)/d\theta^\mu$ is something called a directional derivative. It tells you the rate at which $\ell(\theta)$ changes when you travel in direction $\theta^\mu$. The directional derivative also points in that direction, so $\theta^\mu$ and $\partial_\theta\ell(\theta)/d\theta^\mu$ point in the same direction. Therefore if the $\theta^\mu$ are orthogonal, then so are rhe derivatives in question.